# For CCV2 Portal, is there a way to specify environment-specific properties for Spartacus / JS Storefront?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

For CCV2 Portal, is there a way to specify environment-specific properties for Spartacus / JS Storefront? SAP Commerce has this using `useConfig.properties[x].persona`. How about for Spartacus?

Context: We want Spartacus to use different keys (e.g. API keys) for different environments (e.g. Development, Staging, Production).

Reference: https://help.sap.com/viewer/1be46286b36a4aa48205be5a96240672/v2011/en-US/3d562b85b37a460a92d32ec991459133.html#loio3d562b85b37a460a92d32ec991459133__section_z4k_sht_dhb1

Answer (score 0):

Possible option is to keep the key / property in SAP Commerce side, which can take advantage of `useConfig.properties[x].persona`. Then, SAP Commerce will just expose an API that Spartacus can call to get the value of the key.

Comment: related issue:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/5772